# Как реализовать смерть игрока при соприкосновении с объектом с определенной стороны?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я делал через дополнительный дочерний тригер, но он не совсем правильно растягивается(Это важно для Геймдизайна в будущем). Тригер я делал прям на краю с левой стороны куба.

[image: Что хочу сделать]

Comment: А что именно не получается?

Comment: @aepot 
Мне не удобно растягивать куб, потому что его дочерний тригер тоже растягивается и делает он это не очень коректно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно получить точки соприкосновения и искать от них.
Пример отсюда http://answers.unity.com/answers/783413/view.html

```
 void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D  collision) 
     {
         Collider2D collider = collision.collider;
  
         if(collider.name == "target")
         { 
             Vector3 contactPoint = collision.contacts[0].point;
             Vector3 center = collider.bounds.center;
 
             bool right = contactPoint.x > center.x;
             bool top = contactPoint.y > center.y;
         }
     }
```

*unity предлагает использовать  GetContact вместо contacts
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-contacts.html